# Android: parsing json file

Tags: android, json, parsing

I need to call this URL: https://login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username=name.surname

I obtain a json file format. I need only to take the element associated to tag "status". For the above link is "status":406, so I need the value 406. What is the most simple way for implementing a parser that get only this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do it for this particular situation is

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(myJSONString);
String status=obj.getString("status");
```

You'll have to handle the JSONException incase the tag "status" isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got this response as a string yet? That is your first step but as you are asking for a parser I assume youve done this. If so the rest is easy:

```
String jsonString = parsedString; //The downloaded JSON String
JSONObject firstObj = new JSONObject(parsedString);
String status = firstObj.getString("status");
```